# How to Serialize object in hadoop (in HDFS)

Tags: java, hadoop, serialization, mapreduce, bigdata

I have a HashMap < String,ArrayList < Integer > >. I want to serialize my HashMap object(hmap) to HDFS location and later deserialize it at Mapper and Reducers for using it.

To serialize my HashMap object on HDFS I used normal java object serialization code as follows but got error (permission denied)

```
try
        {
            FileOutputStream fileOut =new FileOutputStream("hashmap.ser");
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            out.writeObject(hm);
            out.close();

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I got the following exception

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: hashmap.ser (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:110)
    at KMerIndex.createIndex(KMerIndex.java:121)
    at MyDriverClass.formRefIndex(MyDriverClass.java:717)
    at MyDriverClass.main(MyDriverClass.java:768)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

Can someone please suggest or share the sample code of how to serialize object in hadoop on hdfs ?

Comment: this seems like File permission issue. However for making it simple pls check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try using [SerializationUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/SerializationUtils.html) from Apache Commons Lang.

Below are methods

```
static Object   clone(Serializable object)  //Deep clone an Object using serialization.
static Object   deserialize(byte[] objectData) //Deserializes a single Object from an array of bytes.
static Object   deserialize(InputStream inputStream)  //Deserializes an Object from the specified stream.
static byte[]   serialize(Serializable obj) //Serializes an Object to a byte array for storage/serialization.
static void serialize(Serializable obj, OutputStream outputStream) //Serializes an Object to the specified stream.
```

While storing in to HDFS you can store `byte[]` which was returned from serialize.
While getting the Object you can type cast to corresponding object for ex: File object and can get it back.

***In my case, I was storing one hashmap in Hbase column, I retrieved it back, in my mapper method as Hashmap as it is.. and was successful in that.***

Surely, you can also do that in the same way...

Another thing is You can also Use Apache Commons IO [refer this](http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/examples/write-byte-array-to-file/) (`org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils`);
but later you need to copy this file to HDFS. since you wanted HDFS as datastore.

```
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File("pathname"), myByteArray);
```

Note : Both jars apache commons io and apache commons lang are always available in hadoop cluster.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can you please tell me how do I write byte[] returned by  SerializationUtils.serialize(obj) method on HDFS and here my serializable object will hashmap object, right ?

Comment: Yes you are right. you can serialize hashmap to byte array. if you deserialize you can take the same hashmap back. I have done that infact, only diff.. is your data store is hdfs by data store is Hbase column. thats all

Comment: yes hashmap implements serializable. if you see the hierarchy. you can get it. see this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur answer sir .