# Store documents (.pdf, .doc and .txt files) in MaprDB

Tags: java, hbase, hue, mapr, nosql

I need to store documents such as .pdf, .doc and .txt files to MaprDB. I saw one example in Hbase where it stores files in binary and is retrieved as files in Hue, but I not sure how it could be implemented. Any idea how can a document be stored in MaprDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is , Im not aware about Maprdb as Im using Cloudera. But I have experience in hbase storing many types of objects in hbase as byte array like below mentioned.

---

Most primitive way of storing in hbase or any other db is byte array. [see my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37546745/647053)

You can do that in below way using Apache commons lang API. probably this is best option, which will be applicable to all objects including image/audio/video etc..

please test this method with one of object type of any of your files.
 `SerializationUtils.serialize` will return bytes. which you can insert.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationUtils;
/**
* testSerializeAndDeserialize.
*
**/
public void testSerializeAndDeserialize throws Exception {

//serialize here
    byte[] bytes = SerializationUtils.serialize("your object here which is of type f  .pdf, .doc and .txt ");


 // deserialize the same here and see you are getting back or not.
 yourobjecttype objtypeofpdfortxtordoc = (yourobjecttype) SerializationUtils.deserialize(bytes);

}
```

#### Note :jar of apache commons lang always available in hadoop cluster.(not external dependency)

another example :

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationUtils;

public class SerializationUtilsTrial {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      // File to serialize object to
      String fileName = "testSerialization.ser";

      // New file output stream for the file
      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);

      // Serialize String
      SerializationUtils.serialize("SERIALIZE THIS", fos);
      fos.close();

      // Open FileInputStream to the file
      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);

      // Deserialize and cast into String
      String ser = (String) SerializationUtils.deserialize(fis);
      System.out.println(ser);
      fis.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

---

***For any reason if you don't want to use `SerializationUtils` class provided by Apache commons lang, then you can see below pdf serialize and deserialize example for your better understanding but its lengthy code if you use `SerializationUtils` the code will be reduced.***

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class PdfSerializeAndDeserExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        File file = new File("someFile.pdf");

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        //System.out.println(file.exists() + "!!");
        //InputStream in = resource.openStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        try {
            for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1;) {
                bos.write(buf, 0, readNum); //no doubt here is 0
                //Writes len bytes from the specified byte array starting at offset off to this byte array output stream.
                System.out.println("read " + readNum + " bytes,");
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(genJpeg.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
```

#### Above you are getting byte array you can prepare put request to upload to database i.e Hbase or any other database

---

#### Once you persisted, you can get the same using hbase get or `scan` you `get` your pdf bytes and use the below code to again make same file i.e someFile.pdf in this case.

```
        File someFile = new File("someFile.pdf");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(someFile);
        fos.write(bytes);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    }
}
```

#### EDIT : Since you asked HBASE examples I'm adding this.. in the below method

`yourcolumnasBytearray` is your doc file for instance pdf.. converted to byte array (using `SerializationUtils.serialize`) in above examples...

```
  /**
 * Put (or insert) a row
 */
@Override
public void addRecord(final String tableName, final String rowKey, final String family, final String qualifier,
                final byte[] yourcolumnasBytearray) throws Exception {
    try {
        final HTableInterface table = HBaseConnection.getHTable(getTable(tableName));
        final Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(rowKey));
        put.add(Bytes.toBytes(family), Bytes.toBytes(qualifier), yourcolumnasBytearray);
        table.put(put);
        LOG.info("INSERT record " + rowKey + " to table " + tableName + " OK.");
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        printstackTrace(e);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'll try to do it on MaprDB. Do you have any examples that you did it on Hbase?

Comment: added one more PDF ser/deserialization example without `SerializationUtils`