# How to load JPG ,PDF files to HBASE using SPARK?

Tags: apache-spark, hbase

I have image files in HDFS and I need them to load to HBase. Can I use SPARK to get this done instead of MapReduce? If so how, please suggest. Am new to hadoop eco system.

I have created a Hbase table with MOB type with a threshold of 10MB size.
Am stuck here on how to load the data using shell command line.
After some research there were couple of recommendations to use MapReduce but were not informative.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/)... along with  `sc.binaryFiles(filesPath)` formats supported by Tika are [formats](https://tika.apache.org/0.9/formats.html)

out of which you need

> Image formats The ImageParser class uses the standard javax.imageio
>   feature to extract simple metadata from image formats supported by the
>   Java platform. More complex image metadata is available through the
>   JpegParser and TiffParser classes that uses the metadata-extractor
>   library to supports Exif metadata extraction from Jpeg and Tiff
>   images.
>   and
>
> Portable Document Format The PDFParser class parsers Portable Document
>   Format (PDF) documents using the Apache PDFBox library.

Example code with Spark see in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42000832/how-to-read-pdf-files-and-xml-files-in-apache-spark-scala/51308758#51308758)

another example code answer given here by [me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41209262/647053) to load in to hbase